# how to get request count at kubernets service endpoint level

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-service

in our Kubernetes cluster we use multiple internal Kubernetes service endpoints. and these service endpoints used by multiple client services.

we wanted to check is there any which we can get the kubernets service level metrics in terms of request count, average response time, status code aggregation?

Comment: which ingress are you using? Are you using any service mesh?

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi we are not using any Ingress. apps access each other on K8s internal service endpoint. also we dont use service mesh.

Comment: @chitenderkumar I am looking for something similar. Were you able to figure this one out ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes service uses Virtual IP (Layer 4) for load balancing which can't give you Application-level metrics (Layer 7)

You will need to install a service mesh to get Layer 7 metrics.

Refer: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/05/managing-microservices-with-istio-service-mesh/